# Initialize class objects problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, class, object

I initialize class objects something like this and it works.

```
$obj = new Model_Person_DbTable();
```

But when do it like this:

```
$className = 'Model_Person_DbTable()';
$obj = new $className;
```

Then it show following fatal error:

```
Model_Person_DbTable() class not found.
```

How can I achieve this in PHP/Zend

Comment: `$className = 'Model_Person_DbTable';$obj = new $className();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try without the brackets (they are not part of the class name)

```
$className = 'Model_Person_DbTable';
```

If that doesnt help, make sure your autoloader and include path is set up correctly.